# Dynamically creating elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am building a list of checkbox items in jQuery based on an array returned from a handler.

The containing element is the `.listContainer` element below and then each dynamic element I want to add to this takes the form of the `.listContainerItem` element. Each item will have checkbox value and label based on the array item creating it.

```
<div class="listContainer">
    <div class="listContainerItem">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
        <div class="listContainerItemLabel">Checkbox 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the point of the function that has the array passed to it, what is the most efficient way of creating this? I have been trying to accomplish it as below, but quickly running into major performance issues.

```
function AddItemToListContainer(item) {
    var currentItems = $j("#listContainerAvailable .listContainerItem");
    if ($j.grep(currentItems, function (e) { return $j(e).find(":checkbox:first").val() == item.Id; }).length === 0) {
        labelDiv = $j("<div />").addClass("listContainerItemLabel").html(item.Text);
        itemToAdd = $j("<div />").addClass("listContainerItem").append("<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"" + item.Id + "\" />").append(labelDiv);
        currentItems.append(itemToAdd);
    }
}
```

I've looked at `.map` function, but not sure quite how to implement it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: As a note: `.append("<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"" + item.Id + "\" />")` can be `.append('<input type="checkbox" value="' + item.Id + '">')` which is just easier to read and debug.

Comment: Do you get the list of items at once and can you replace the whole set of checkboxes or will it append only a few new at any time?

Comment: I have a separate function that first removes anything from the DOM that is not in the array, so all I need to then do is check that each item isn't already represented in the DOM and if not add it.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like this:

```
var $container = $j('#listContainerAvailable');
var checkboxes = {};

function AddItemToListContainer(item) {
    if (checkboxes[item.Id]) return false;

    checkboxes[item.Id] = true;

    var $item = $j('<div />', {
        'class': 'listContainerItem',
    }).appendTo($container);

    $j('<input />', {
        'type': 'checkbox',
        'value': item.Id
    }).appendTo($item);

    $j('<div />',  {
        'class': 'listContainerItemLabel',
        'text': item.Text
    }).appendTo($item);
}
```

As long as none of these elements exist when you create the page, you can add them to a hash table instead of searching through the DOM. I think you'd also benefit from a JS templating engine like [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#readme)

Answer (score 1):

When pressing the button of the code it will check if the input field has been filled in
if it is empty it will alert you with a pop-up
If it isnt empty it takes the value of the input field, create a checkbox and put the value of the input next to your checkbox.

HTML of the form

```
<form name="formName" id="listContainerItem">
    <input id="newinput" type="text" value=""/><button id="button">Add new rule</button> <br />
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" /><span class="listcontainerItemLabel" />Checkbox 1 <br />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(#button).click(function() {
function addLine(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var x = document.getElementById('newinput').value;
        if(x == '') {
            alert('not filled in')
        } else {
            $('#listContainer').append('<input type="checkbox" value="1" /><span class="listcontainerItemLabel" />'+x+  '<br />')
        }
    }
```

});

remember `document.getElementById('newinput')` can also be written like this: `$('#newinput')`

all you got to do is change what will be appended a bit with your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to have these elements appear one at a time? or just be dynamically created from an array on page load?

For the last:

html

```
    <div class="listContainer">
       <div class="listContainerItem"></div>
     </div>
```

and jquery

```
var array = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

 $.each(array, function (index, value) {
    $(".listContainerItem").append('<input type="checkbox" value="' + value + '" /> <div         class="listContainerItemLabel">Checkbox ' + value + '</div>');
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jeremythuff/HEKjk/

And some .click events can give you the first effect

Answer (score 0):

You can use many ways to dynamically create....

```
$("#elementid").after("<input type='checkbox'></input><span></span>;

$("#elementid").before("<input type='checkbox'></input><span></span>;

$("#elementid").append("<input type='checkbox'></input><span></span>;

$("#elementid").prepend("<input type='checkbox'></input><span></span>;
```

like wise you can use `insertAfter()`, `insertBefore()`, `appendTo()`, `prependTo()`.....